# How exactly does one detect if it is in a curved manifold?

Tags: differential-geometry, mathematical-physics

This may be a philosophical or physical question, so feel free to report me.

However, I was reading about how scientists (in the spirit of the motivation of Poincare's conjecture) tried to measure curvature of our three dimensional space to see if it is curved for a possibility that we live in a curved space, to see if it is possible for us to travel in a geodesic/straight line in the universe and be able to get back to where we started.

But my question is, how does a being on a manifold measure its intrinsic properties like curvature, as in, how would we actually know if we are moving in a curved path or a straight bath given that we live on the Riemannian manifold?

For instance, living on earth, assume for the sake of argument earth is a perfect sphere, one way to know that we are walking in a straight line would be to hold up a straight ruler, project the ruler on earth orthogonally and follow that path which will be a segment of a great circle, hence it is a geodesic. However, this already employs the fact that the surface of the earth is an embedded manifold in $\mathbb{R}^3$ and the metric is the induced metric from the ambient manifold. If we were truly a 2-dimensional being living on the surface of the earth, this would not be a viable option. In fact, the way we define covariant derivative rigorously is by the tangential Levi-Civita connection which requires that we first computing the covariant derivative of a curve in $\mathbb{R}^3$.

So now we are in a much more similar situation as 3-dimensional being living in 3 dimensional space (I'm aware that we actually live in spacetime that is a 4-dimensional pseudo-Riemannian manifold, yes). How exactly would we measure curvature in space - living in space and having no awareness of an ambient manifold (As far as I know the Whitney's embedding theorem is non-constructive)?

Thank you

Comment: Have you read about the sum of the angles in a [spherical triangle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spherical_geometry) and why this is not 180 degrees? A two-dimensional being should be able to make those measurements even without a degree in philosophy or physics.

Comment: @Kurt G. No I have not, and that does answer my question. Sorry if my concern with possibly going off tangent from math offended you.

Comment: @Kurt G. Actually I'm still a bit confused with this approach, because to use sum of angles of a triangle to detect curvature, don't we still need to know what it means for a line to be straight? Which goes back to my question, how does one do that without referring to an ambient manifold (again, computing covariant derivatives and knowing that the geodesics on a sphere are the great circle).

Comment: A "straight" line is the shortest distance between two points. With all the buzzwords you are dropping I think it is not too much to ask to get familiar with the basics of differential geometry and ask a more focussed question. MSE cannot reproduce a personalized introduction from scratch.

Comment: @KurtG. A "straight" line in Riemannian geometry is a geodesic, which is a curve whose covariant derivative of its velocity field is zero. All these "buzzwords" are rigorous definitions of how a geodesic is defined. Just because you are unfamiliar with Riemannian geometry enough to understand the rigor of the question doesn't mean someone's question is not focused. Perhaps you should review some basic Riemannian geometry before presuming to answer questions on MSC.

Comment: @KurtG. And even if you form a triangle with 3 lines which each being the shortest path between each point, how exactly, pray tell, do you know it has the shortest distance without appealing to a Riemannian metric - and if you knew the metric already then of course the curvature is known, so why bother using the sum of angle theorem? (barring from any known physical law, since you are so confident that this question is not worth the attention of someone with a physics degree)

Comment: The two dimensional being does not need to know what a covariant derivative is to find the shortest line between two points. This is physically so simple that it is almost embarrassing to give you a hint: you heard of chords?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You mention 3-dimensional and 4-dimensional manifolds but what you should review is the notion of [Gaussian curvature](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gaussian_curvature) of a 2-dimensional manifold (i.e., a surface).  Gaussian curvature is an intrinsic invariant, in that to calculate it, one does not need an isometric embedding of the surface into Euclidean space.  The simplest definition of Gaussian curvature does make reference to an embedding in 3-space (it is the product of the principal curvatures, or the determinant of the [Weingarten map](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Differential_geometry_of_surfaces#Shape_operator)).  However, [Gauss](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Carl_Friedrich_Gauss) proved that it is independent of the embedding!

Comment: So are there any intrinsic properties of a 3-dimensional RM one can use to measure to detect curvature/non flatness with?

Comment: Or actually, if our 3 dimensional space , or more generally n-dimensional space is curved, then we can easily find an embedded surface in our space that would be curved/non flat (even though it may appear flat to us), so that its Gaussian curvature can be measured to be non zero.  In particular, as Kurt G. mentioned, there would be triangles such that their angles do not add up to 180 degree. And I imagine one can prove that if you have a space where all triangles have sum of internal angles add up to 180, it is a flat space?

Comment: There is a generalisation of Gaussian curvature to higher-dimensional Riemannian manifolds.  It is called *sectional curvature*, or more explicitly "curvature in 2-dimensional directions".  @Ecotistician

Comment: I see, so back to my original question, how do we know if a line is straight in our universe, not knowing if it is flat to begin with? It seems circular to me (And this is why I think this may be a physics or philosophical question), as someone informed me above: to try to measure if our space is flat they use sum of internal angles of triangles to see if it adds up to 180 degree, but to form a triangle we need to know if the lines we define the triangles with are straight - but to know if these lines are straight/geodesics, we need to know if they are curved in the first place.

Comment: The notion of a "straight line" is replaced by the notion of a geodesic both in Riemannian geometry and in semi-Riemannian geometry (which is relevant for relativity).  @Ecotistician

Comment: I'm aware of that, hence I used the word straight line and geodesic interchangably. My question is then how do they know , that the triangle they are forming are in fact, geodesics - velocity field which is not changing along the curve - where change is computed by the covariant derivative along curves - to begin with. Seems like if you know the lines you are forming are geodesics , then you should be able to compute the curvature directly. @Mikhail Katz

Comment: In the example of the sphere mentioned in the comments above, the geodesics are precisely the great circles.  A spherical triangle is a triangle whose sides are arcs of great circles.  By the Gauss-Bonnet theorem, the angular excess (over $\pi$) is precisely the area of the triangle.  @Ecotistician

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/152359/discussion-between-ecotistician-and-mikhail-katz).